# basic css issue removing hyperlink underlines

Tags: html, css

Bear with my rudimentary question.

http://jsbin.com/css-play-notfound/6

There is this blue underline thats annoyingly creeping up between my image and Text in the  heading.

Comment: who down voted this? Basic questions need to be answered too! be kind!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things you can do:

Change this code:

```
<img src="logo.png" alt="REUNIFY" height="35" />
```

to this:

```
<img src="logo.png" alt="REUNIFY" height="35" border="0" />
```

Also add this to your CSS stylesheet:

```
a { text-decoration:none }
```

Note that the above CSS will get rid of the underline on ALL links. So if you want your normal
text links to have the underline and just want this particular link to NOT have the underline,
then create a class like so:

```
a.noline { text-decoration:none }
```

and then change your HTML code to this:

```
<h1><span><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org" class="noline">
<img src="logo.png" alt="REUNIFY" height="35" border="0" />
</a></span>
Welcome
</h1>
```

Comment: You should remove image borders in your CSS resets. No point putting it on every img tag individually. Also, image needs a width attribute and is a self containing tag.

Comment: Just read from w3schools about how explicitly specifying dimensions on images pre allocates space for it.

Comment: Also found normalizer.css instead of doing resets. Also, i understand it ships with bootstrap, which i plan to use subsequently.

Comment: I am not clear about the border =0 property in image. any explanation ?

Comment: Some browsers add a blue border around an image by default, you should always have img border:0; in your CSS file to remove this.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the css rule...

```
text-decoration: none;
```

... to your `<a>` element, or to one specific element by using a class or ID.

You can apply it to all hyperlinks like so:

```
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always add HTML5 and older browser CSS resets.

http://cssreset.com/ has the most popular ones of 2012. This way, you'll always be starting on a clean slate.

Answer (score 1):

```
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

add this in your css